# React native Connection status on background / locked screen NetInfo

Tags: react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

**Description:**
When the app is running in a background state or Locked, When the user unlock or foreground the app, useNetInfo(); hook return as isConnected as false. Even I tried to re-fetch the state still using *`NetInfo.fetch()`* return the same state.

It's happening in Android real device connected to Wifi

***Package Name:***
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.2",

**Code:**

```html
 const netInfo = useNetInfo();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShow(!(netInfo.isConnected && netInfo.isInternetReachable));
  }, [netInfo]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchConnection();
  }, []);

  const fetchConnection = () => {
    NetInfo.fetch().then((state: any) => {
      setShow(!(state.isConnected && state.isInternetReachable));
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by reverting the package version into `"@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.7"`,
Also, change the `androidXCore` version into 1.6.0. Now it's working as expected.

**Reason:**
Due to the hibernation features changes in `androidXCore` version [1.7.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#1.7.0). `Netinfo` does not return the state properly if the app is in a hibernation state. Please fix this issue in the upcoming release. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add [navigation focus event listener](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/) and check for network update whenever the screen is focused.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it's from the package npm site

```
useEffect(() => {
    const subAppState = AppState.addEventListener("change", async (nextAppState) => {
      if (IS_IOS_DEVICE && nextAppState=='active') {
        let newNetInfo = await NativeModules.RNCNetInfo.getCurrentState('wifi');
        //your code here 
      }
    });
    const unsubNetState = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
        //your code here
    });
    return () => {
        if (subAppState) {
            subAppState.remove();
        }
        unsubNetState();
    };
  },[]);
```